# PHP foreach echoing strings

Tags: php, string, foreach

I want to echo these links as following:

```
Title
http://www.link.com
Title 2
http://www.link2.com
```

Instead they come like this:

```
Title
http://www.link.com
http://www.link2.com
Title2
http://www.link.com
http://www.link2.com
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
    foreach($links as $link ){
    echo $link."<br>";
        foreach($linksx as $linkx ){
    echo $linkx."<br>";
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's because you are looping over the *entire* `$linksx` array for *each* element in `$links`.

Comment: If $links contains the title and $linkx the url you should have a single 'for' to interact over both lists at same time. Here your second foreach is printing all urls for each title.

Answer (score 4):

As you have 2 differents arrays, you have to iterate over them on the same time, not one inside the other.

Assuming arrays are indexed numerically (basic array), and have the same size (the same number of elements), you can write

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($links) ; $i++)
{
    echo $links[$i] . "<br />";
    echo $linksx[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are looping over the *entire* `$linksx` array for *each* element in `$links`.  What you want is to loop over one array then get its counterpart in the other array.

```
foreach($links as $key=>$link){
    $linkx = $linksx[$key];
    echo $link."<br>".$linkx."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Woah, thank you exactly what I was looking for, how is there anyway to remove the last output from $links?

Comment: @user1938320: You mean the trailing `<br>`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to nest the loops?

```
foreach($links as $link )
{
    echo $link."<br>";
}
foreach($linksx as $linkx )
{
    echo $linkx."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Nope, using your code they come as

Title
Title2
http://www.link.com
http://www.link2.com

I want to output 1 title and 1 link at a time. Thank you for your help